# Increase number of characters in Subject Field:Email-to-Case

Tags: email2case

Can you please also increase the length of the subject field when you are creating an e-mail as an activity from a case. It currently still limits you to 100 characters.

When I try to set 200 above characters it is accepting but case is not getting created.

**Code:**

```
Integer x;
    Integer subjectLength;
    Map<Id, String> mapAsset_Case = new Map<Id, String>(), mapAccount_Case = new Map<Id, String>();

    if (trigger.isInsert) {
        for (x = 0; x < trigger.new.size(); x++) {
                if (trigger.new[x].Subject__c == null) 
                subjectLength = trigger.new[x].Subject.length();

                    if(subjectLength > 199)
                    {
                      trigger.new[x].Subject = trigger.new[x].Subject.substring(0,199);
                      trigger.new[x].Subject__c = trigger.new[x].Subject;
                    }
                    else
                        trigger.new[x].Subject__c = trigger.new[x].Subject;
```

please see the above code and give me any solution in this.

Comment: "Can you please also increase the length" - Did you mean for this to go to someone at Salesforce support or your local support?

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what issue you are having as you say it is accepting the case but not creating the case which seems to be a contradiction.

If you are speaking about the ability to create an email activity with a subject > 100 characters in length (Your first line in your question) then please see below:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176857&language=en_US

> There is the 100 character limit on the Email Subject field within the
>   UI. Note: Starting Winter'16 we have added a new feature where a
>   maximum of 650 characters in email subject line is displayed using the
>   Email Publisher in Case Feed only. **The limit of 100 characters on the
>   Send an Email task (Email Author) still applies.**
>
> However, the subject field can store 4000 characters in the database.
>   **If the data is entered via the API (Email-to-Case, Data Loader,
>   Integrations, etc.), more than 100 characters can be entered, and will
>   be stored in the database.** The UI will actually display more than 100
>   characters if the Subject is longer than 100 characters, as long as
>   the email was created via the API (not limited by UI constraints);
>   however, outbound emails from within Salesforce are limited to 100
>   characters.
>
> The Email Subject field has a hybrid length in order to maximize
>   compatibility, both inbound and outbound. Some email platforms allow
>   senders to enter more than 100 characters, which is why the field
>   allows inbound email to store thousands of characters, to ensure that
>   if an email is received with a large Subject line, the value will be
>   retained. Other email platforms may truncate subjects longer than 100
>   characters, or even 50 characters. We limit the Subject length for
>   outbound email in order to avoid truncation as much as possible once
>   the email reaches the intended recipient.
>
> This document explains the field, but does not mention any specifics
>   about length:
>   http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm#topic-title
>
> This discussion may also be helpful in explaining the reasons:
>   https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000JGHiEAO

Comment: Thanks for the Info @Eric.
Is it possible to increase the characters in standard Subject Field in Case Object.

Comment: @CharanTeja - No